# How to add a Setup project through Visual Studio DTE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, setup-project

I am trying to develop a template Visual Studio 2008 solution making use of the `IWizard` interface. So far I have been able to successfully add multiple projects to the solution. I am now looking to put in a Web Setup project into the solution which will already have the Project Output from a particular project specified.

I read that a `.vdproj` file cannot be part of a template, so looking at any other alternate options available.

One option that I tried but did not work was to save the contents of the `.vdproj` file within the wizard and write it out after the solution gets generated. I am wondering if I can use the Visual Studio `ExecuteCommand` to add a Project and add the Output Group in the setup project without displaying the UI.

Anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

The method of saving the contents of the `.vdproj` file within the wizard works. However, before writing out the content to a file and adding it as a project, the GUID of the project which would be used in the Setup project (`Project Output` or `Content Files`) has to be replaced in the saved text.

Visual Studio adds a unique project GUID once the project gets added to the solution, and this GUID has to be read using the Visual Studio SDK and replaced in the actual `.vdproj` file text.